# Parse error: unexpected DB_USER T_STRING in wp-config.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm copying a website to a different domain name on the same server - which is something I usually don't do.
I copied the public_html using FileZilla and created a new database (and uploaded the old database in this new database) using the same username and password as the original database. I changed the new database name in the wp-config.php file but now I keep on getting the following error:

**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'DB_USER' (T_STRING) in **/home/*username*/*website*/public_html/wp-config.php** on line **22**

My wp-config file is the following:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database’);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username’);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I filled in the database name correctly. I didn't change the password and username as they are the same as in the previous database.

Who knows what's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The error is here:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database’);
```

The last tick (just after `database`) should be a single quote (') instead of a back tick (`).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a typo, try :

```
define('DB_USER', 'username');
```

Instead of:

```
 define('DB_USER', 'username’);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the database user password. 
But I didn't restart mysql service.

After restart of the service, everything worked like a charm.
Also always check PHP_error.log file. (in C:\Windows\Temp)